# Jquery find multiple links href with same class and change name for each link depending on get page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, href

I have this design:

**HTML Welcome Page**

```
<div id="links">
<a class="view" href="www.this.com/43534534534"><span class="link_number"></span>This one for all</a>
<a class="view" href="www.this.com/99540594544"><span class="link_number"></span>This not but why not</a>
```

....100 of those here.....

```
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#links').find('a.view').each(function(){
  quickC = $(this).attr('href');
  $.get(quickC, function(html){
  var quantity = $(html).find('a.my_text').size();
  $('.link_number').append(quantity);
   });
});
```

**HTML Page #1 www.this.com/43534534534**

```
<a class="my_text">this this</a>
<a class="my_text">this this this this</a>
<a class="my_text">this this this</a>
```

**HTML Page #2 www.this.com/99540594544**

```
<a class="my_text">this this</a>
<a class="my_text">this this this this</a>
```

...

**RESULT FROM JQUERY**
Page #1 = found 3 links
 
Page #2 = found 2 links

...

**DESIRED RESULT**

**HTML Welcome Page**

```
<div id="links">
<a class="view" href="www.this.com/43534534534"><span class="link_number">**3**</span>This one for all</a>
<a class="view" href="www.this.com/99540594544"><span class="link_number">**2**</span>This not but why not</a>
```

....100 of those here.....

**THE PROBLEM/QUESTION:**

Everything works except I don't know why it pulls only first link and spread the same number to other link_number classes.

Question, how to make this code work as I may have 100 of those links with specific href and return processed link number to the related a.view link on welcome page?

Your input appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: so what you are trying to do it find out how many `<a>` tags are on each page? im a little lost as to what your trying to do with each `<a>` tag

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. So I have welcome page. On that welcome page I have links with same class but different href. I am using Jquery to get to specific href page in that <a>, search for number of <a> with class my_text on those other pages, and return attach quantity of found <a> to the name of each link on welcome page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$('.link_number').append(quantity);` will find all the spans, not just the one inside the active link you're downloading. So you have to pass the actual link object to the function that set the number of links, so it can find only that one span:

```
$.get(quickC,{},{linkobj: $(this)}).success(function(html) {
    var quantity = $(html).find('a.my_text').size();
    $('.link_number', this.success.linkobj).append(quantity);
});
```

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of checks I propose the following solution:

```
    $(function() {
        $('#links').find('a.view').each(function(index) {
            var quickC = $(this).attr('href');
            $.get(quickC, function(data) {
                var quantity = $('<output>').append($.parseHTML(data)).find('a.my_text').size();
                $('span.link_number').eq(index).append(quantity);
            });
        });
    });
```

Hope that works!